# How do I give NSText multiple shadows?

Tags: objective-c, macos, text, core-graphics, osx-mountain-lion

Right now I'm using

```
NSShadow *textShadow = [NSShadow new];
textShadow.shadowBlurRadius = 5;
textShadow.shadowColor = [[NSColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.5];

[self addAttribute:NSShadowAttributeName value:textShadow range:NSMakeRange(0, self.length)];
```

from an NSTextStorage to give text a shadow. But I want to apply more than one shadow, and adding another `NSShadowAttributeName` just overwrites the previous value.

How can I add more than one shadow? Can it be done with `CGContextSetShadowWithColor`?

Comment: Are you looking for something color to string inside textview??

Comment: No. I just want to apply more than one drop shadow to text.

Comment: It would be gr8, if you can paste output sample here

Answer (score 3):

Not sure please try this below code for your textview. When you write string inside textview it will select that much range and on the basis of that it draws the color:-

```
-(IBAction)createNewTabView:(id)sender
{
   NSString *allTheText =[tv string];
    NSArray *lines = [allTheText componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]init];
    NSMutableAttributedString *attr;
    BOOL isNext=YES;
    [tv setString:@""];
    for (str in lines)
    {
        attr=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:str];
        if ([str length] > 0)
        {

        NSRange range=NSMakeRange(0, [str length]);
        [attr addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[NSColor greenColor] range:range];
        [tv .textStorage appendAttributedString:attr];
            isNext=YES;
        }
        else
        {
            NSString *str=@"\n";
            NSAttributedString *attr=[[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:str];
            [tv .textStorage appendAttributedString:attr];
            isNext=NO;
        }
        if (isNext==YES)
        {
            NSString *str=@"\n";
            NSAttributedString *attr=[[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:str];
            [tv .textStorage appendAttributedString:attr];

        }

    }
    }
```

Comment: It's not the background color I want. I want to add more than one drop shadow (`NSShadowAttributeName`).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the "caveman" approach.  Instead of trying to get duplicate shadows, use duplicate Text's, all but one of which has it's color set to the clear color, and give them different dropShadows.

- make two ore more text's that line up exactly.
- make the front most your "real" text color.
- make the other text's clear color.
- set one type of shadow for each type of text.

You should be able to make a class that automates this, if you are going to use it multiple times.

This is a sample of what I got:

[image]

oh-- if you don't make the additional text's your text will appear much darker/bolder than you expect.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the opacity of the text color seems to effect the opacity of the shadow as well. Also, rendering multiple overlapping text views is pretty inefficient, especially when you're working with large, multi-page documents.